# Is Spyder 4.1.2 newer than 4.1.3?

Tags: version, spyder

I stated Spyder in Ubutun 20.04. It said that "Spyder 4.1.3 is available! ". I have installed the version 4.1.2. On the command line I got a message:

```
(base) jaakko@jaakko-Lenovo-IdeaPad-L340-17IWL:~/Desktop$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                            
Hit:3 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal InRelease                                       
Hit:4 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                          
Hit:5 http://archive.canonical.com focal InRelease                                                           
Get:6 https://gitlab.com/paulcarroty/vscodium-deb-rpm-repo/raw/repos/debs vscodium InRelease [3 828 B]
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                      
Fetched 3 828 B in 1s (3 978 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
(base) jaakko@jaakko-Lenovo-IdeaPad-L340-17IWL:~/Desktop$ sudo apt install spyder
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
spyder is already the newest version (3.3.6+dfsg1-4build1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgnutls-openssl27 libvpx5
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

So what is going on here as 4.1.2 is newer version than 4.1.3? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that

a) Spyder tests for new versions against its own servers

b) The Ubuntu respository does not yet offer version 4.1.3, so 4.1.2 is the newest it knows

So the program will offer the new version, but your `apt` won't be able to install it because it lacks a source for the newer version.

Comment: Ubuntu doesn’t even have Spyder 4.1.2 (see the logs, they refer to 3.3.6), so the OP is using another release, probably installed using PIP.